# How does Settings control in ubuntu alter the settings in real time?

Tags: mouse, application-development, settings, source-code

I have noticed that in Ubuntu, unlike windows, there is no "apply settings" button. I am wondering how is it possible to alter settings in real time. I mean there is some variable in some file getting altered when we are in the process of alteration, say mouse pinter speed, and that very variable is also being read by the other processes related to mouse function.

I am sorry its a vary vague question but I am currently studying operating systems and I am really curious to know the background mechanism employed by Ubuntu Developers.

Thanks

Comment: Lookup gsettings

Comment: Windows does exactly the same thing; the presence or absence of an "Apply" button comes from considerations of user interface. In Windows, the programmers wanted to give the user the option to play with the dialog box then change their mind and press "Cancel". In other desktop environments the programmers preferred to give the user immediate feedback of the effect of the choice. Long story short, the "Apply" button is there for the user and not for the system. And the settings _files_ are for long-term storage; the actual settings which are applying right now are in memory.

Comment: @AlexP so the running system accesses the memory or storage when taking actions based on setting ?

Comment: @user19961: In principle, memory. However, you are speaking of studying operating systems, but most of the settings dialog boxes you are describing refer to the desktop environment, which is an ordinary application and not part of the operating system *per se*.